# HTML5 mobile boilerplate build script empties HTML files

Tags: html, ant, mobile, boilerplate, build-script

All files seems to have run through the build script without any problems except my HTML files. They get added to my publish folder but are completely empty. I have tried both `ant build` and `ant minify`.

If i comment out this line `file.pages.default.include  = index.html, 404.html` the files don't get emptied.

One more weird thing happend to. My generated css version started at around 40 the first time i ran the script. Doesn't matter at all really. Just a bit odd.

Update:
I noticed i get this error. `ERROR: For JavaScript or CSS compression YUI compressor jar file must be present in the same directory as HtmlCompressor jar`.

Read a thread where Paul Irish was saying that updating to the latest htmlcompressor jar should solve it. I did that but some reference somewhere needs to be updated with the new filename to cause now i get an error saying that the htmlcompressor jar couldn't be found.

Comment: Can you add a link to the project or post the code?

Comment: Sure, the project can be downloaded from here http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/

I have version 1.1 and i haven't changed anything in the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same issue, this has just been answered at the mobile boilerplate site: https://github.com/shichuan/mobile-html5-boilerplate/issues/46